# Iterate JPA query result

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

Is there a way to iterate query results through JPA API, similar to Hibernate's `Criteria.scroll()` method? It is big performance improvement with big resultsets, rows can be processed as they are read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not such a construct in JPA. Also not in [JPA 2.1](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf).

JPA 2.2 provides TypedQuery.[getResultStream()](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/), but default implementation does not have expected effect (calls getResultList). Also specific implementations do not always lead to performance improvements, as can be seen in [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2-stream-the-result-of-a-query-execution/) article.

Comment: Maybe it could be proposed. I think it is useful.